# Proof that a sequence with a lower bound converges to Infimum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I am preparing for my exams, and came across the following question(translated into English): Let A have a lower bound so that infA=I. Prove that a subsequence a(n) exists so that this subsequence converges to I.

I’m caught between using the Sandwich theorem or monotonic subsequences inherent in any sequence. Both have not brought me to the desired result. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean a sequence, right? So you have a set $A$ and you want to find a sequence that converges to the infimum of $A$?

Comment: Yes sorry a sequence a(n)

Answer (score 2):

Either there is an element $x\in A$ such that $\inf A=x$ or there is no such element. If there is such element take $a_n=x$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. If there is no such element we must do something else. First by definition we have for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $x\in A$ such that $\inf A > x-\epsilon$. So you can find sequence $a_n\in A$ such that $\inf A>a_n -\frac{1}{n}$ by choosing $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ and repeating the process for $n=1,2,3,...$. That means $0\leq a_n - \inf A < \frac{1}{n}$. Hence $|a_n -\inf A| < \frac{1}{n}$. And that means $a_n \to \inf A$.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the given order, what you want to prove is not always true.

Example of a partial order:

$\inf\{x\mapsto\sin(kx),k\in\Bbb Z\}=-1$, but $\forall k\in\Bbb Z$, $\|x\mapsto\sin(kx)+1\|_{\infty,\Bbb R}=2$.

Example of a total order:

$\forall x,y\in\Bbb R,(x\mathcal R y\iff f(x)\le f(y))$ with
$$
f:\ x\mapsto
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x=1$} \\
1, & \text{if $x=0$} \\
x,  & \text{if $x\in\Bbb R\backslash\{0,1\}$}
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\inf(1,2)=0$, but $\forall x\in(1,2)$, $|x|\ge1$.